# Query regarding why and how to use highcharts license

Tags: highcharts

1. As far as I can understand any enterprise which uses highcharts product need to purchase the license but we don't add it in code then why do we need highcharts license ?? 
   Because without purchasing license also I can use highcharts library to develop something.
   Please correct me if I'm wrong.
2. How to use highcharts license actually, like do I need to include it in some code file ?

Comment: This should be sent to highcharts support directly. This site is for code support (not just of Highcharts but all kinds). See here for contact info: https://www.highcharts.com/support

Comment: I read that document but no exact answer to my queries, so asked this question here because anyone who has used the license would know this

Comment: We have a license. It is a "good faith" license. We purchase support as well. No code file requires the license.

Comment: Please contact *sales@highsoft.com* if you have any questions about licensing.

Comment: The software is available for download from high chart website. There is no mandatory license key associated with the software, and no activation is needed. The License is solely a legal document and consists of two parts: The Terms and Conditions and the License Statement. These documents are attached to the order confirmation email you received after the completion of your purchase

Answer (score -5):

Don't have to place the license key anywhere, you need it just to contact support or sales. Just in case of bugs and version update issue, they will give direct support to licensed partners.